# Load and using a font, but just in a single paragraph in an entire document

Tags: fonts, formatting, font-encodings

I have a book document with a lot of formatting, and I would like my dedication paragraph to appear in a font, that will just be used here, in the entire document. Let's say I want to use Tex Gyre Chorus ([here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyrechorus/)) to be used in that paragraph.

How to do this, without breaking everything, and inadvertently affecting the fonts I use for the rest of my document?

Here is a toy example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sf=false]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
Hello World! I would like this text to appear in Tex Gyre Chorus.
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document

Comment: You are looking for `qzc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: vincentChorus]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{lmodern}% Why?
\usepackage[sf=false]{libertine}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\fontfamily{qzc}\itshape  Hello World! I would like this text to appear in Tex Gyre Chorus.}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```